# How to enable ZK Page to bind with non public properties of bean

Tags: zk

How to enable ZK Page to bind with non public properties of bean.

Say I have a domain object called Book which looks like

```
class Book{
private String name;

protected String getName(){
return name;
}

protected void setName(String name){
this.name = name;
}
}
```

I want to be able to bind a textbox using @{book.name} , at present I think to enble binding i will need to make the getter and setter as public.

Frameworks like hibernate can operate on non public properties as well, so why has zk choosen not too, an configuration change possible to enable this ??

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks
Sudarshan

Answer (score 0):

Subclass it with making these accessors public and use the subclass instead of class Book.

Comment: That is not a very elegant solution, I would have a class bloat with each class that needs to be shown in the UI needing to be sub classed, And also i think its a abuse of inheritance.

Comment: That is violation of encapsulation - the thing you want to do. Otherwise you can make an Aspect which will do the same thing as I proposed but in Run-time (with SpringAspects) or in After-Compile (with AspectJ).

Comment: Well, I do intend to keep my properties private and do not want to expose public getters and setters so for most of application it is encapsulated, however i do agree that at the UI layer it is being compromised, however that is a trade off i am willing to make, I was wondering if zk provides ways of doing it ..

Comment: Either your program design has something wrong or you mislead yourself in way from a root of your problem to some non-evident workaround. What was your motivation in the first place?

Comment: What you could actually do is:  - provide use interfaces instead of classes;  - create classes which had protected fields from Factory;  - make those protected methods you have public and use them only in UI.  And again, it's not a ZK problem, so it's better to just remove zk tag and make it a general java question. You'll have a horde of people who could help you to find a solution.

Comment: my motivation -- is simply to query a domain object from the DB and show it on the screen, most zk hibernate examples do just that, the only twist being i do not want to expose the properties of my domain object via public getters and setters to the rest of my application ...

Comment: I have kept the ZK tag only because, my question  is related to exposing non public getter setters on the UI, and my UI layer is ZK ...

Answer (score 0):

Domain model definition:

```
public interface Book {
  // some public methods you want to expose
}
```

Domain model implementation:

```
// This class is of package visibility
class BookSomewhatSpecificImplementation implements Book {
  private String name;

  // Note that they are package-scoped.
  String getName(){
    return name;
  }

  void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Object factory:

```
public final class DomainModelFactory {
  public static Book createBook(/* Some parameters */) {
    return new BookSomewhatSpecificImplementation();
  }
  private DomainModelFactory() {}
}
```

Summary: you should program all other modules against Book interface. You can still use reflection for model implementation. To produce do mane objects use the factory.